# The photo copier might be making my colleague sick

Tags: colleagues, health, thailand

In my office they are 19 people including me. My IT manager normally comes to office late and leaves at night. Today I spot one thing that might be a problem, the photo copier. I like to sit at his desk to wait my printed paper from the photo copier. My throat was sore after inhaling the emissions from the photo copier. The IT manager says that he has the same issue. I think he intentionally comes to office late and start working quite late until night to avoid the photo copier.

I know it is none of my business, but sometime his coming late at work is problematic.

**Question**
How can I address that photo copier might harm his health condition to company?

Comment: *Photocopiers create ozone through their "corona wires" that apply a charge to the paper so the ink will cling to it. As ozone is highly reactive, any adverse health effects will be found essentially at the sites of initial contact – the respiratory tract (nose, throat and airways), the lungs and at higher concentrations, the eyes.* [Office Photocopiers: Health Hazards](https://www.healthxchange.sg/wellness/health-work/office-photocopiers-health-hazards)

Comment: If the room has little ventilation, and/or the windows are always closed then the photocopier poses a health hazard to everyone in the office, not only to your IT manager. So, you need to mention IN your question how old the copier machine is, whether there is a window near it or not, *and* how long your manager has been coming in late.

Comment: Having the country would help here too.

Comment: Have you talked to the IT manager casually about the your sore throat after sitting next to the copier?

Comment: Consider relocating the photocopier... Go for the problem not the symptoms.

Comment: Have you asked why your manager has adjusted his working hours?  The reason might have nothing at all to do with the photocopier.

Comment: Agreed with @Snow that you are making a lot of assumptions without talking to the manager. We have lots of people at my office that arrive and leave late, usually to avoid traffic, or just because they have a later sleep schedule.

Comment: @jcmack It happens in Thailand. My company is big one in the US and Europe, but it is small branch in here

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't know how old is it. Company rents it from vendor. It is in the middle of the room :(

Comment: @jcmack Yes, I have. He confirms he has that issue

Comment: Side note: For health reasons, the German Berufsgenossenschaft/Unfallkasse associations demand that "office multifunction printers/copiers are placed in separate rooms without individual workplaces" and that these rooms are to be well ventilated. Desktop laser printers are to be kept either at least 1m from the next workplace, or below the desk.

Comment: @Alexander Thank you very much for sharing. I need reference to make a change on this problem. In Thailand they are very few companies that aware on this.

Comment: @Sarit https://www.unfallkasse-nrw.de/sicherheit-und-gesundheitsschutz/themen/biol-chem-phys-einwirkungen/drucker-kopierer.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### You don't need to bring your coworker into things at all to bring this up with the appropriate people in your company.

It's very considerate of you to be concerned about your coworker's health, but you don't need to mention him or any assumptions about his schedule or other behaviors. I would even suggest that you not mention the coworker's schedule (it might possibly cause problems for him, and gains nothing for you).

Instead, you can explain your personal experience. *You* were sitting at the photocopier, and *you* felt unwell due to that. That's the experience you can bring to someone's attention, and you can still express your concern for your coworker's health:

> I wanted to mention that the other day I was sitting by the copier waiting for my things to print. After only a minute of sitting there I smelled/felt in my throat something unpleasant, which I think was some kind of emission from the copier. My throat got really sore, and I'm worried that the copier might cause health problems for us. I was only there for a couple of minutes, I can't imagine how bad it must be for [IT manager]!
>
> Could we look into having it checked by a technician, moving it to a better-ventilated (or at least less populated) area, or getting a newer, safer one?

Comment: This answer is good sense it points out, you don’t actually know, if the copier is making the individual sick.  Their schedule might be approved and have absolutely nothing to do with the copier.